# Unable to query or connect, depending on bind-address

Tags: mysql

I have a simple script that is failing differently depending on the bind-address configuration.  If I set bind-address to the IP address of the server and run the script the query times out.  If its set to anything else (127.0.0.1, 0.0.0.0) or commented out if fails to connect.

The script is written in [Rebol](http://rebol.com) using a [library](http://softinnov.org/rebol/mysql.shtml) that connects to MySQL over TCP (i.e. it doesn't use libmysql).

I'm wondering if there's something about my MySQL configuration that is causing these issues but I'm kinda stumped as to what to change.

EDIT - Here is some sample code:

```
do %mysql-protocol-pre.r                                                                                            
db: open [scheme: 'mysql user: "testuser" pass: "testpass" host: "localhost" path: "/mysql"]                   
foo:  send-sql db "SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'foo'"
```

Which results in:

```
** Access error: port action timed out: make port!
```

Comment: Basically `MySQL` uses this format for authentication `someuser@somehost` : means a given username from a given host. If host IP changes you cannot login. You may need `someuser@'%'` for any host...there are other alternatives like Subnets, LDAP...

Comment: Please add the script and the error message

Comment: @185140777 Script and error added above.

Comment: Could you provide the outputs of `strace` or `truss` (whichever is available on your platform) something like:

`$strace_or_truss $script_command_line 2>&1 |egrep 'connect'`

with both types of `bind-address` mentioned in post.